# Cargar valor en un Select cuando modificas registro

Tags: php

Dispongo de un `select` que en caso de querer modificar el registro de la tabla al cargar, no se me ocurre otra cosa de que tire la variable y después dar las opciones. En el caso de `selects` de las tablas no tengo problema, el problema es cuando son unos valores fijos que he puesto.

¿Cómo debería proceder?

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <label for="">Estado</label>
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="estado_ta" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
        <option value="<?php echo $estado_ta ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $estado_ta ?></option>
        <option value>Seleccione</option>
        <option value="En curso">En curso</option>
        <option value="Completado">Completado</option>
        <option value="Parcialmente hecho">Parcialmente hecho</option>
        <option value="Pospuesto">Pospuesto</option>
        <option value="Cancelado">Cancelado</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu problema no se entiende bien. Si tienes valores fijos pues hazlos dinámicos y listo. Pero no se entiende bien que es lo que realmente necesitas, o que errores tienes de lo que ya has intentado...

Comment: que es lo que deseas hacer en el select? cargar datos de una tabla o como? explica un poco mejor para poder ayudarte

Comment: Disculpad ya que a veces ni yo mismo me entiendo.

Comment: Matizo la pregunta, en caso de cuando tengo un select con valores fijos que no tiran de tabla, como hago para que al cargar el valor de la variable quite de la lista el valor que es, o si en caso de cargar el valor que se quede en la opción del select que le corresponde.

Comment: Hola. Aclara tu aclaración, porque no se entiende: *como hago para que al cargar el valor de la variable quite de la lista el valor que es, o si en caso de cargar el valor que se quede en la opción del select que le corresponde*. Si no te entiendes, aplica el [Método de Depuración del Patito de Goma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Método_de_depuración_del_patito_de_goma). A veces el problema no es el código, sino **no saber explicar el problema**.

Comment: Disculpad, vuelvo a describir desde el principio y a ver si es entendible: Dispongo de un select como veis arriba que tiene cinco opciones. Al querer cargarlo en una pagina para editar el registro, lo lógico es que me cargue la opción que ya dispone en su campo (de ahi que lo llamo con un echo), pero no se como hacer que el campo que ya sale se quite del listado del select, por lo que aparece en primer lugar el dato del campo registrado y después el valor por el select. Agradeceros vuestra ayuda ya que soy novato en programacion y stackoverflow me saca de muchos apuros.